# Streaming Icecast through flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, icecast

Hi my name is Tamer and this is very first post in stackoverflow as far as I know. :)

I've been searching this for an issue of mine for a while but haven't found any solutions yet. I want to forward my radio broadcast from it's original host to my embedded flash player once the play button is hit. Is it possible via action script (flash - as3) ? My broadcast is in Icecast format, and I'm playing mp3 but my mount point is not exactly /listen.mp3. It has some more extention like ?auth and some random fixed stuff (I mean, there are some other things at the end of the auth part, but it's same all the time like a fixed link).

Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can play your stream with Flash.  It doesn't matter what your mount point is.  Just plug in the real URL for the stream.  The file name extension and what not doesn't matter.

Comment: I searched over the Internet and I came up with something related to Netstream.Play code yet I'm trying to figure it out how it works. Is there any clear tutorials for it about how to use it? Because the ones that I found is not that much clear. :\

Answer (score 0):

When using the above answer high memnory use may be an issue for your viewers as the "Sound" variable downloads the data while playing.

Would be better off using progressive play/download but would have to change your streaming format from mp3 as it only allows for M4A streaming (AAC audio data in an MP4 container).

```
var netConnection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
netConnection.connect(null);
var netStream:NetStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
netStream.play(“http://your.stream.url/stream.m4a”);
```

Just my 2cents :)